# aptoncd-metapackage error ubuntu 14 offline machine

Tags: aptoncd

I have 2 computers, 1 at workplace (online) and 1 at home (offline). The online computer at workplace got mp3 and other codec for multimedia and it also has vlc. What I want is to copy the package for mp3 codec and vlc to the offline computer so I can play music and video. I already try to use aptoncd and this what I did
- On the online computer I sudo apt-get install aptoncd
- Run aptoncd to collect package
- I check the meta-package option and then make iso file 
- Burn iso to cd

However, when I run the cd on the offline computer by launching aptocd-metapackage with ubuntu software center to restore package I get this error "Dependency is not satisfiable: aptoncd"

What should i do to solve this,thanks

Answer (score 0):

## To install Ubuntu applications offline with AptonCD:

Using a PC with `Ubuntu 14.04.2` installed, via the `Ubuntu Software Center` or via `Synaptic Package Manager`  install all the applications you want, including **aptoncd**.

- Then create a Debian package installer CD or DVD:

Go to System ---> Administration ---> `APTonCD`.

Click `Create` to make an ISO image.

To select your file.deb packages, choose `Add Packages` and it will automatically load packages already on your system.

Select the `Burn` button.

Select your ISO format `DVD or CD`, `destination folder`, and `image file name`.

Click `Apply`.

After the `ISO` is created, you can burn it onto a `CD` or `DVD`.

- Restoring a program using the CD or DVD:

Go to System ---> Administration ---> `APTonCD`.

Click `Restore` to install the application.

Load and select the `CD` or `DVD.`

Make sure to check `Auto-select dependencies`.

Now, select all of the programs you want to install.

Click the `Restore` button. This will copy and store programs on your APT cache folder.

From here it gets a bit tricky; you'll need to use the command line terminal.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then enter `your password`.

After it finishes installing, close the terminal and browse your installed applications.